# Number of distinct values represented by a sum (or product) of two functions?

Tags: calculus, probability, combinatorics

Suppose I have two functions $f, g$ with
$$
N = \# \{ f(n): 1 \leq n \leq 1000 \}
$$
and
$$
M = \# \{ g(n): 1 \leq n \leq 1000 \}. 
$$
Say $N \leq M$.
What is an upper bound for $\# \{ f+ g(n): 1 \leq n \leq 1000 \}$?
I think $N+M$ is an upperbound for this quantity. Is this a sharp upper bound?

What can one say about $\# \{ fg(n): 1 \leq n \leq 1000 \}$?

Comment: In short, no, $N+M$ isn't necessarily an upper bound.

Comment: I see. What would be the upper bound?

Comment: In terms of the given constants and independent of the exact definitions of $f,g$, the best upper bound you can have is $\min(1000, MN)$.  It's the same for both the sum and the product.

Comment: For example, let $f$ follow the pattern $1,2,4,8,1,2,4,8,1,2,4,8,\dots$ and let $g$ follow the pattern $16,16,16,16,32,32,32,32,64,64,64,64,128,128,128,128$.  We have the sums $1+16, 1+32, 1+64,1+128, 2+16, 2+32, 2+64, 2+128,\dots$ giving $4\times 4 = 16$ outcomes, more than just $4+4=8$ outcomes.  Similar examples can be crafted

Comment: Or to go farther, use $f(n)=n, g(n)=1001n$, so $M=N=1000$. Now $f(n)+g(n)$ takes on $MN=10^6$ values.